# angular2 tinymce exception - missing properties from object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, tinymce

I'm trying to use tinymce in my Angular2 project with no success;
I get the tinymce object but it's missing some properties, the exception I get is "Cannot read property 'Factory' of undefined":
[image]

the exception is coming from theme.js: "ThemeManager.add('modern'..."

webpack imports:

`resolve: {
        ...
        alias: {
            'tinymce': path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js'),
            'tinymce-theme-modern': path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js')...`

it occurs when I call tinymce.init function in ngAfterViewInit.
i have typings custom declaration as well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work; 
webpack configurations didn't fit.
The configurations that solved the issue:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: require.resolve("tinymce/tinymce"),
                loaders : [
                    "imports?this=>window",
                    "exports?window.tinymce"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /tinymce\/(themes|plugins)\//,
                loaders: ["imports?this=>window"]
            }...
```

I have another exception now:

```
plugin.js:19 Uncaught module definition dependecy not found: tinymce/util/Tools
```